# UIScrollView doesn't bounce

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView **contained within a custom UIView** with a content size larger than the ScrollView's frame.

I am able to drag scroll as I expect, but the thing doesn't give me the rubber banding effect that you get with the UITableView or UIWebView. It just stops when you get to one of the extremes.

I have set `bounce = YES`, is there something else I'm supposed to do?

I read the docs, and they say I have to implement the delegate. I did that.

They also say I should change the zoom levels, but I don't want the user to actually be able to zoom so I haven't set these.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For anyone that finds this thread later, if you are subclassing `UIView` and re-setting the `UIScrollView`'s frame on every `layoutSubviews`, that is the problem - it cancels the bounce:

http://openradar.appspot.com/8045239

You should do something similar to this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews;
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = [self calculateScrollViewFrame];
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(frame, self.scrollView.frame)) 
        self.scrollView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Wasted hours of misdirected effort down various rabbit holes before suspecting this. Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem, on a UIScrollView that wasn't all filled up (but I still wanted it to bounce). Just setted:

```
scroll.alwaysBounceVertical/Horizontal = YES;
```

And it worked as expected

Comment: Very helpful when you have a refresh control on the scroll view but doesn't contain enough to bounce (which prevents the refresh control from working).

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that keeping the UIScrollView within my custom UIView was causing the trouble.

Once I switched my custom UIView to instead inherit from UIScrollView, then the bouncing started working.

Comment: I'm having this issue with nested UIScrollViews. I checked that subviews' frames are not modified unnecessarily when calling layoutSubviews as the openradar link states and I'm also using an UIScrollView Subclass for the inner scrollView that's not bouncing

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting...  Is there a lot going on while the user scrolls the scroll view?  Maybe that could cause the problem.  The iPhone can multitask, but not too much.  Can I see your entire code having to do with the scroll view?

Comment: Nothing interesting going on at all! There's just a scroll view with a large UIView added as a subview whose frame is the same size as the scroll view's content size. The subview has a bunch of custom UIViews as children.